# Is it correct to write "free-of-the-war"?

Tags: adjectives, writing-style, hyphenation

Is it correct in English to write *"free-of-the-war"* as an adjective via hyphens?

For example, *"I live in a **free-of-the-war** part of Ukraine"*

And how about *"yet"*? That is *"yet-free-of-the-war"*

Comment: Why do you think it would be?

Comment: *I live in an as-yet war-free part of Ukraine*.  So, yet can be used. But I am not going to write a full answer here. :)

Comment: Your best bet is to read English-language journalism about the war in Ukraine, and see what phrases it uses for areas far from the fighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English prefers heavier syntactic elements like phrases and clauses to fall to the **right** of a Noun Phrase’s head, not to its **left** the way lighter elements like determiners, adjectives, and noun adjuncts do.

The word *free* is an adjective, but *free of the war* is too long to precede the head. So we’ll place to the left, with either an indefinite or definite article at the front:

1. I live in **a** part of Ukraine that is free of the war.
2. I live in **the** part of Ukraine that is free of the war.

You can don’t have to write *that is*, let alone say it. In speech that would nearly always come as a contraction *that’*.

3. I live in a part of Ukraine **that’s** free of the war.

But you don’t really need it at all:

4. I live in a part of Ukraine free of the war.

You asked about adding *yet* before *free*. You can do that in both versions, but it’s better to use *still* for this:

5. I live in a part of Ukraine which is still free of the war.
6. I live in a part of Ukraine that’s still free of the war.
7. I live in a part of Ukraine still free of the war.

The reason you want *still* is because *yet* works better in negative contexts, perhaps like:

8. I live in a part of Ukraine that hasn’t been touched by war yet.
9. I live in a part of Ukraine that hasn’t yet been touched by war.

You could make an ad-hoc compound modifier *war-free* and place this to the left of the noun where adjectives fall:

10. I live in a war-free part of Ukraine.

However, you couldn’t really say a *still-war-free* part, because that again becomes too “heavy” to come before the noun.

Answer (score 1):

"Free-of-the-war " is not found as a construction of English. That is, "free-of-the-war" can't be considered as a valid adjective, for the time being at least; "free-of-war" is not used either.

You may say "a war-free part of Ukraine".

[war-free *](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+war-free+%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ca%20war%20-%20free%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20war%20-%20free%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20war%20-%20free%20Europe%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20war%20-%20free%20zone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20war%20-%20free%20country%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20war%20-%20free%20society%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20war%20-%20free%20future%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the expression as an adjective, you are correct that it should be hyphenated.  It would not be "wrong."  As for "yet," if you use the hyphenated adjective, I would leave yet as a seperate word.

The stylistic suggestions of the other responses make good points.  You may want to use a simpler construction.